# VSCode will not recognize variables in templates

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm following the Lynda Course titled Learning AngularJS 2 and i've done the assignements to get the app working. It compiles fine and works as intended in the browser. However, *Visual Studio Code* is giving me problem warnings in all of the template-files:

> Identifier 'artist' is not defined. The component declaration, template 
>   variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

**artist-details.component.html**:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="assets/images/{{artist.shortname}}.jpg" alt="{{artist.name}} photo">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-4">
    <h2 class="mt-3 mt-sm-0 mb-0">{{artist.name}}</h2>
    <h4 class="mt-0">{{artist.reknown}}</h4>
    <p>{{artist.bio}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**artist-details.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist-details',
  templateUrl: './artist-details.component.html',
  inputs: ['artist']
})
export class ArtistDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }    
}
```

I've installed the *Angular Essentials* extension.

Comment: Yes, seems bug in extension

Comment: show component code

Comment: I've updated the question to include component code

Answer (score 0):

Well i found out and it seems like a Visual Studio Code bug.
Writing `artist['name']`instead of `artist.name` makes the warning go away.